# Access nested properties using inspect in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and I am trying to understand a code. For this reason I apply the `inspect` method to an object like this

`search_form.inspect`

I get the following result:

```
#<Search::SearchForm:0x000055a6f1fa5da0 @field_options=#<Search::SearchFormFieldsOptions:0x000055a6f1fa5c38 @profile_id=467, @profile_date=Sat, 28 Feb 2015 22:00:00 UTC +00:00>, @types=[:datasource], @bit_operations=[], @datasource_relations={0=>"set"}, @datasources={0=>nil}>
```

I want to dig deeper and see what's inside `@field_options`. I tried accessing it via `search_form.field_options` and `search_form['field_options']`, but it didn't work.

So how to inspect or get the values of these inner properties 
that i see when using `.inspect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch instance variables for introspection using [instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
seach_form.instance_variable_get(:@field_options)
```